# DataGridView in Windows C#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

Can i design datagridview of windows form control, Like Datalistview of webcontrol.

Like vertical align datagridview(Column and data).

Any suggession?

Comment: Have you tried ListView control? It has also lot of properties which can customize it.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx